# QlikView field name as a dimension in expression

Tags: expression, dimension, qlikview

My chart contains this dimension:
`=if(vDim1='[Column1]','Column2',)`
but if I do this I will actually have the value "Column2" written in every cell.

How can I make QlikView interpret Column2 as a column name, as opposed to a value?
I know it works if I use a variable vDim2 that is equal to: [Column2]:
`=if(vDim1='[Column1]',$(vDim2),)`
, but I am interested to know if there is a solution that doesn't use variables? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think just removing the quotation marks will give you what you want.

```
=if(vDim1=[Column1],[Column2])
```

I think the key concept is when are you telling QlikView to return the text in a field or to return only the text you have typed in.

Have a look at this example of using the text qualifier (') vs not using it.

[image: Text vs Field]

In the expression editor you can see what QlikView is expecting red words are fields and black ones are text

[image: Qualified Text]

[image: Field Names]